# JAVA - Performance Bottleneck with Spring Integration Router

Tags: java, performance, activemq-classic, spring-integration

im woring in a system with Spring integration and i need to activate differents services depending on the messages recived from an MQ Queue, i'm routing this messages based on its content, for that purpose im using an Spring Integration *recipient-list-router* with *selector-expression*.

Testing the performance of this config, im getting a bottleneck on this router.

```
<int:recipient-list-router id="Router" input-channel="inputChannel" default-output-channel="tslOutputChannel"> 
    <int:recipient channel="xmlOutputChannel" 
        selector-expression="payload.startsWith('&lt;?xml')" />
</int:recipient-list-router>
```

After routing the messages, i'm using a Spring Integration Filter and transformer, then the messages are sent to a service activator.

What can i do to improve the router's performance? and would be better to do this routing, filtering and service call with a JAVA class?

Thanks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhCGZ.gif)

Comment: It would be interesting to know what part of the router is slow as the selector should be quite fast. Alternatively, you can build your own router... just extend `RecipientListRouter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unlikely SpEL is a huge bottleneck here but you can write a Java router, or you can try configuring the [SpEL compiler to compile the expression](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-spel-compilation).